# When i click on particular data(location) in the first fragment i want to navigate to the second fragment and show a marker on the map and data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have two fragments implemented using `View Pager`. In fragment 1 I have list of data with the location coordinates and in fragment 2 I have map, which is showing all data according to the location coordinates.

When I click on particular data in the first fragment I want the app to navigate to the second fragment and shows a marker on the map and data in the info window.

When I click on particular data I am able to move on the second fragment using `setcurrentitem()` method. But how do I show that particular location only?

If anybody knows, please suggest me a solution. I need to do this as soon as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are calling `setcurrentitem()`, pass Latitude and Longitude data to Fragment 2, put this code in Fragment 1:

```
    Fragment2 f = new Fragment2();

    // Supply value
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong("latitude", location.getLatitude());
    args.putLong("longitude", location.getLongitude());
    f.setArguments(args);
```

Fetch value in Fragment 2 :

```
    Long latitude = getArguments().getLong("latitude", 0);
    Long longitude = getArguments().getLong("longitude", 0);
```

Using `latitude` and `longitude`, you can show `marker` on Google Map in Fragment 2

Comment: In fragment 2, I am already showing all the location. I just want to show that particular location which was clicked in fragment 1 and hide all othr location.

Comment: I am not creating new Fragment2, i just want to display location in the existing fragment. If i create a new fragment then i will have to replace the existing fragment with the new one

Comment: clear the map markers before displaying that fragment2. For example, you can use the map.clear() before displaying the pin from the fragment1.